# Laravel 5 - Compile String and Interpolate Using Blade API on Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Using the Blade service container I want to take a string with markers in it and compile it down so it can be added to the blade template, and further interpolated.

So I have an email string (abridge for brevity) on the server retrieved from the database of:

```
<p>Welcome {{ $first_name }},</p>
```

And I want it to interpolated to

```
<p>Welcome Joe,</p>
```

So I can send it to a Blade template as $content and have it render all the content and markup since Blade doesn't interpolate twice and right now our templates are client made and stored in the database.

`Blade::compileString(value)` produces `<p>Welcome <?php echo e($first_name); ?>,</p>`, but I can't figure out how to get $first_name to resolve to `Joe` in the string using the Blade API, and it doesn't do it within the Blade template later.  It just displays it in the email as a string with PHP delimiters like:

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo e($first_name); ?>,</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// CustomBladeCompiler.php

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError;

class CustomBladeCompiler
{   
    public static function render($string, $data)
    {
        $php = Blade::compileString($string);

        $obLevel = ob_get_level();
        ob_start();
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);

        try {
            eval('?' . '>' . $php);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) ob_end_clean();
            throw $e;
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) ob_end_clean();
            throw new FatalThrowableError($e);
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$first_name = 'Joe';
$dbString = '<p>Welcome {{ $first_name }},</p>';

return CustomBladeCompiler::render($dbString, ['first_name' => $first_name]);
```

Thanks to [@tobia](https://laracasts.com/@tobia) on the [Laracasts forums](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/render-template-from-blade-template-in-database).

Comment: I used a temporary blade template instead of buffer, but this way is much better)

Comment: if I use a @foreach  the $php value contains this:  $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $app): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop();  ;.... (where $__env is not accessable) any idea.

Comment: @SimonFakir 
$path = resource_path('views/' . $id . '.blade.php');
file_put_contents($path,$needCompileString);

Comment: @PaulBasenko say much better but temporary blades good choice if need all blade functionalitiy, foreach not working go rewriting code:(.

$output = view("temp." . $id , $yourData)->render(); 
Enjoy.

Comment: How can I use this with Mailables ?

Comment: If my dbString like `<p>Welcome {{ $name }}`,  then i got error like `Undefined variable: name `.But, I want to get result like `<p>Welcome {{ $name }}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: This just saved me! I wonder if this is still the way to do this?