# Parse content from function as were it Blade contents

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've got a blade view in which I load another string via a function called `retrieveSomeContent()`

`retrieveSomeContent()` returns a string, which could hold 'references' like `{{ $action->url }}`. The data itself is available in the view.

```
// myView.blade.php
// simplified
...
  {{-- doesn't work 
       displays {{ $action->url }}
   --}}
  {!! retrieveSomeContent('section1B') !!} 

  {{-- works --}}
  {{ $action->url }} 
...
```

Off course the view right now will just displays `{{ ... }}` as text instead of parsing it to `http://.....`.

How would I be able to parse the string generated via `retrieveContent()`?

Comment: If  `{!! retrieveSomeContent('section1B') !!}` returns `{{ $action->url }}` it will, not work. It should only returns `$action->url` instead.

Comment: Well, the function returns ‘raw’ un processed blade directrices and variabels. As it also contains ‘normal’ text, i cannot only return $action->url

Comment: `{!! '..' !!}` will be parsed as `<?php echo '..' ?>` So you can't include partials like this. Maybe you are looking for [`@include` directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: Yeah that would be great! Except @include only loads view files (as far as i know) not strings.

Comment: As far as I know, in Laravel you can't (natively) render a string as a view/partial. I found [this alternative](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compileString), and an [example of usage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801582/laravel-5-compile-string-and-interpolate-using-blade-api-on-server) That's **maybe** what you need.