# Generate URL from the string blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am fetching the string data from the database which is nothing but a blade template body.

```
Ex. $x = "<p> <a href={{ url('/test') }}> Get Started </a> </p>"
```

In blade template, it is rendering as {!! $x !!}

Which is compiling the HTML properly but not able to evaluate the {{ url('/test') }}.

I have tried to achieve this by Blade::compileString but it won't work.

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802153/3348994

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you print $x, it is printing text. You can call `url()` when you are setting `$x`. Try this:

```
$x = "<p> <a href='". url('/test') . "'> Get Started </a> </p>";
```

This will call `url` before sending to the view, considering that you are calling it in the controller or model.