# Laravel Blade: parse/process raw string/data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I hope this question is not duplicated.

How can I use Laravel Blade to parse raw strings/data and use the output? For instance, when I try the following code I get the following exception:

```
$processed = view('Hello {{ $name }}!', [
    'name' => 'John doe'
])->render();
```

> No hint path defined for [Hello {{ $name }}!]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [Illuminate\View\Comilers\BladeCompiler::compileString($value)](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compileString)
which gets a string content and renders a view from it. Experiment a bit, look up the documentation and you should be fine. I haven't used it myself, so I'm not really familiar with it, but I knew it existed somewhere. Hope that helps!

Comment: How should I bind the variables from array?

Comment: After all you're rendering a string. Why not replace the variables directly in the  string?

Comment: I know it can be done easily without using Blade. I want to know if this can be accomplished using it though.

Comment: There are several topics online on how to implement this. Turns out, it's not that simple. Take a look at those:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/render-template-from-blade-template-in-database ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801582/laravel-5-compile-string-and-interpolate-using-blade-api-on-server ,
https://gist.github.com/AlexR1712/83e502e25300fcfeb4199b88f3bdce49